# Make onsen-ui sliding menu to scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, onsen-ui

I am using onsen ui to build an app and have got a very long menu:

```
    <ons-template id="menu.html">
        <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
            <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent"></ons-toolbar>
            <ons-list class="menu-list">
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('updates.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-updates"></ons-icon>Updates</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('about.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-about"></ons-icon>About</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('venue.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-venue"></ons-icon>Venue</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('agenda.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-agenda"></ons-icon>Agenda</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('speakers.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-speakers"></ons-icon>Speakers</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('sponsors.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-sponsors"></ons-icon>Sponsors</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('resources.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-resources"></ons-icon>Resources</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('feedback.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-feedback"></ons-icon>Feedback</ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('register.html', {closeMenu: true})">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-register"></ons-icon>Register</ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
```

When I am in a small screen and scroll down the menu it stays in the same position and doesn't go back to the initial view.

Code for the menu:

```
<ons-sliding-menu menu-page="menu.html" main-page="updates.html" side="left" var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="200px" swipeable="true" ons-postclose="menutotop()"></ons-sliding-menu>
```

I implemented **ons-postclose="menutotop()"** but it doesn't seem working with jQuery.

Does anybody know how to make it scroll back to the top as soon as it closed by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create an Angular controller and add it into a `div` element, which will wrap the `ons-sliding-menu` element. If you want to use jQuery, your code will be like this (see also the working [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/avaJzX?editors=101)).

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController"><ons-sliding-menu  menu-page="menu.html" main-page="updates.html" side="left" var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="200px" swipeable="true" ons-postclose="menutotop()"></ons-sliding-menu></div>
```

**JS**

```js
ons.bootstrap()
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.menutotop = function() {
      $('.page__content').animate({
          scrollTop: $('.ons-list-inner').height()
        })
        .animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        });
    }
  });
```

I hope it helps!